# Take value from radio button to choose an image in html

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a chat application. this the code for display the conversation in chat page:

```
<div id="conversation">
  <div id="messages" class="scrollbar col-md-6">
    <ul ng-repeat="(k,v) in messageshistory " class="chat" data-ng-show="k == tmpuserid">
      <li ng-repeat="(a,b) in v ">
        <span ng-class="(b.from == tmpuserid) ? 'chat-img pull-right':'chat-img pull-left'">
          <img src="./img/avatar.png" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle">
        </span>
          <div class="col-md-10 chat-body clearfix" >
            <div class="header">
              <small data-ng-if="b.from == tmpuserid" class="text-muted">
                <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> {{ b.time }}
              </small>
                <strong ng-class="(b.from == tmpuserid) ? 'pull-right primary-font':'primary-font'" >{{b.fromname}}</strong>
              <small data-ng-if="b.from != tmpuserid" class="pull-right text-muted">
                <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>{{ b.time }}
              </small>
            </div>
                <p>{{ b.message }}</p>
         </div>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

so in this application, the register page is not with upload a photo for their avatar. so I use 
`<img src="./img/avatar.png" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle">`

but I want to add 'gender' in register page with radio button, like:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
</form>
```

and when user check 'male' in register, he will use
 
`<img src="./img/maleavatar.png" alt="Male Avatar" class="img-circle">`

when user check 'female' she will use 
`<img src="./img/femaleavatar.png" alt="Female Avatar" class="img-circle">`

what I mean is, this application will has two images for avatar, if male use male, if female use female, how do I write it?

Comment: @demo but in my case is, the image option is in other page, not in the same page

Answer (score 0):

You could add both the images to your HTML and then use the correct one with a `ng-switch` on the user gender (there are enough sources on [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) and radio button binding for you to find a solution).

Hope this puts you on track, if not just ask back.

Comment: I think its may the answer, but the 'gender' is in the 'register' page and the 'avatar' is in 'chat' page. before go to chat page, user must log in first. so, this data will jump many pages. can I use this?

Comment: Keep your data nice and tight inside a service (fetch data from the server on login, store them in a variable inside the service and access them from everywhere by injecting the service) and that won't be a problem.
(Extend the method in this [tutorial](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services) with $http/$resource logic.)